# Blogs about digital cartography?

Tags: cartography

I´m looking for blogs or good websites about digital/web cartography...i´m not really interested in the deep technical ramblings (i´ve the forum lists for that) but rather inspirational blogs which showcase great digital cartographic techniques or projects and how they are created.

If there are such things here in the web, please let me know...I´,m also interested in statistical visualisation blogs like these..http://datavisualization.ch/showcases/, http://flowingdata.com/...but I´ve never seen such blogs which specialise in digital/web cartography.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A Starting List for Digital Cartography**

http://mycarta.wordpress.com/

http://artcarto.wordpress.com/

http://bigthink.com/blogs/strange-maps

http://mappingcenter.esri.com/ {ESRI Centric}

http://kelsocartography.com/blog/

http://www.mapsandthecity.com/

http://gis.blogoverflow.com/tag/cartography-2/

Answer (score 6):

Here's a good one from my old university lecturer.
http://cartonerd.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Some good and funny commentary there, reminds me of [Cartastrophe](http://cartastrophe.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Lots about contemporary mapping and web carto at:

http://mapperz.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't read Gretchen Petersons blog/website: http://gretchenpeterson.com/ it is highly recommended. She also has two booklets, "Type for maps" and "color for maps" and a book "GIS cartography" for sale (haven't read them, but from the booklet samples they seem good)

Answer (score 3):

My list:

http://www.cartogrammar.com/blog/

http://www.radicalcartography.net/

http://samplecartography.com/work.html

http://www.maproomblog.com/

http://www.bigmapblog.com/

http://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/

http://mapoftheweek.blogspot.com/

http://timwallace.wordpress.com/

http://makingmaps.net/

http://flowingdata.com/

http://indiemaps.com/blog/

http://chadrobin.blogspot.com/

http://oliviasmapcatalog.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting London focused work gets showcased on the [Mapping London](http://mappinglondon.co.uk/) blog from the guys at [UCL CASA](http://casa.ucl.ac.uk/). The Guardian Datablog (http://www.guardian.co.uk/news/datablog) also features some mapping work amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

Many fine ones have already been listed.  Here are a couple more that I follow or scan regularly:

- http://makingmaps.net/
- http://andywoodruff.com/blog/
- http://cartastrophe.wordpress.com/
- http://cartophile.tumblr.com/

These data vis sites also often have cartographic products that they profile:

- http://infosthetics.com/
- http://uxblog.idvsolutions.com/
- http://chartporn.org/  (an unfortunate name choice, IMHO, for a
  professional blog, but worth following)

And, this was posted last week too on Flowing Data - http://flowingdata.com/2012/04/27/data-and-visualization-blogs-worth-following/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a blog, the new article rate is too slow for that, but when I'm seeking inspiration or just want to kick back for awhile and marvel at awesome work I go to Tom Patterson:

http://www.shadedrelief.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some interesting maps with interactive / digital cartography can be found here :

http://www.bellerbyandco.com/blog/random/interactive-cartography/#.Um5wrpRmWQg

Answer (score -1):

I have a blog that there are interesting maps about a city of the Brazilian Amazon (Belém/PA) as well as many types of cartographic representation, articles with many maps about differents matters as: Violence, desflorestation, population, among others. If you want know, click here please http://geocartografiadigital.blogspot.com.br/. You can like and share. Thanks a lot!